# LFE: why $E=0$ implies that $|u^{\prime}|=a$ for a constant $a>0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, velocity

Consider this easier formulation of the relativistic Lorentz force equation given by
\begin{equation}\
\left(\frac{u'}{\sqrt{1-|u'|^2}}\right)'= E(t,u)+u'\times B(t,u).
\end{equation}
Here,  $E$ and $B$ denote respectively the electric and magnetic fields and are given by
\begin{equation}
E=-\nabla_u V-\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}, \qquad B=\mbox{curl}_u\, W,
\end{equation}
with $V:[0,T]\times (\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}) \to\mathbb R$, $W:[0,T]\times\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$  two $C^1$-functions.

During class, it has been said that if $E=0$, thus the equation is autonomous and also $|u^{\prime}|=a$ for some positive constant $a$.
Could someone please explain me why that is true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, I can't help but comment that using $u$ for position and $c$ for a speed that is not the speed of light is extremely confusing. But anyway, the reason is the same as in the classical equation: the acceleration is orthogonal to the velocity.

In more detail, the left hand side of the equation is equal to $f(u') u''$, with some function $f(u')$. The time derivative of $|u'|^2$ is $2 u' \cdot u''$. If we take the Lorentz force equation and dot it with $u'$, the right hand side gives zero because of the cross product. We then get $f(u') u' \cdot u'' = 0$, so that $u' \cdot u'' = 0$ and the magnitude of $u'$ is constant.

Comment: Javier, thank you for your useful answer. Do you specify that $|u^{\prime}|^2 = 2 u^{\prime}\cdot u^{\prime\prime}$ just to highlight that the rhs of the equation is equal to $f(u^{\prime}) u^{\prime\prime}$ for some function $f(u^{\prime})$? Or there is another reason? Thank you.

Comment: Also, could you please explain why $u^{\prime}\cdot u^{\prime\prime}=0$ gives that $|u^{\prime}|$ is constant? It could not be that $u^{\prime}\perp u^{\prime\prime}$?

Comment: @C.Bishop It's most definitely not true that $|u'|^2 = 2 u' \cdot u''$! The right hand side is the *derivative* of the left. Therefore, if the right hand side is zero (and the force equation tells us that it is), $|u'|$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic part of the Lorentz force does zero work on point particle, because it is perpendicular to its velocity. Consequently speed can't change due to magnetic part of the Lorentz force. Electric part is needed to change speed.

Geometrically, magnetic force only rotates the velocity vector, it can't change its length.

Comment: Ján Lalinský, thank you for your answer. Do you mean that velocity can not change in any direction? If so, it means that any component $u_i^{\prime}, i\in\{1, 2, 3\}$ is constant?

Comment: No, velocity components do change due to magnetic part of the Lorentz force. But they change in such a way that magnitude of velocity does not change. The velocity vector rotates, it does not grow or shrink.

Comment: Ján Lalinský, could you please explain why $u^{\prime}\cdot u^{\prime\prime}=0$ implies that $|u^{\prime}|$ is constant? It could not be that $u^{\prime}\perp u^{\prime\prime}$?

Comment: This is basic kinematics. When rate of change of vector is always perpendicular to that vector, the vector only rotates. If the vector got longer, the rate of change would have a 
 non-zero component in direction of that vector. If it got shorted, the rate of change would  have a component in direction opposite of that vector.